# Converting into pdf from doc in java without using openoffice

Tags: java, pdf, doc

I need to convert my doc file into pdf using Java based desktop application. I am not able to use any kind of server or open office.

Can you please give a piece of code to do so. or suggest me any java open source API.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple API (several of which are open sourced) available to help you with this. Some suggestions would be as follows:

- [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) library is an open source Java tool for working with PDF documents. You might consider using this.
- Another option would be to use [Apache™ FOP (Formatting Objects Processor)](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/)
- [iText](http://itextpdf.com/)

Answer (score 2):

[Here are some suggestions for it](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/130906/looking-for-api-java-to-convert-.doc-into-.pdf#).